# Mysql, insert before declaring cursor in procedure

Tags: mysql

It is possible to insert values into table before declaring cursor in procedure? I need that inserted value to use it in cursor. something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc(IN val_1 VARCHAR(45),IN val_2 VARCHAR(45),IN val_3 INT,IN val_4 SMALLINT)

BEGIN
insert into table1 (value1,value2,value3,value4) values (val_1,val_2,val_3,val_4);

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR 
FOR

select value1 from table1 order by value1 asc limit 1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN cursor1;
read_loop: LOOP

FETCH cursor1 into a;

IF done THEN
leave read_loop;


END $$
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations.

So, No you cannot have an `insert statement` before the declaring your `cursor`.

In the future just go to [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare.html)